# Can not access request object in component. $this->request is null in component after upgrade to cakephp 4.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

How can I access request object and session data in my Component in cakephp 4.0?

I've got the following error **Call to a member function getSession() on null** after upgrade in the following code
`$session = $this->request->getSession();` in my component.

Answer (score 6):

To access Controller from within a component one should use `$this->getController()` (https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components.html#accessing-a-component-s-controller).

To access session you can use `$session=$this->getController()->getRequest()->getSession()`.

Comment: you have upgrade tool that fixes all changes from previous version.